# cap deploy - RVM not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I get this log:

```
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as 
ubuntu@13.58.220.78: rvm exit status: 127
rvm stdout: bash: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin/rvm: No such file or directory
rvm stderr: Nothing written


Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rvm exit status: 127
rvm stdout: bash: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin/rvm: No such file or directory
rvm stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => rvm:check
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

After performing cap production deploy.
The point is, that RVM is installed there, in the exact path it is looking for.

Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this in the end to resolve this (took hours):

```
ln -s /usr/share/rvm/bin/rvm .rvm/bin/rvm
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
set :rvm_custom_path, '/usr/share/rvm'
set :rvm_bin_path, '/usr/share/rvm/bin/rvm'
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add rvm to PATH variable. Otherwise capistrano can not find it neither you can run it from CLI.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
export PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Add this lines in your home directory's .bashrc file. Make sure to restart the session or `source .bashrc`.

Comment: still the same, unfortunately.

Comment: su into deploy user and add it there. Or the user you are deploying on.

Comment: I am deploying using root user, so I added it to root bashrc.
And still the same

Comment: can you run rvm from route user after adding the lines to bashrc??? And just to be clear we are talking about the remote machine. Not your local one

Comment: Indeed Peter, rvm command works well on the server, but capistrano still don't recognize it.
I found a workaround for the issue, using rvm install from the deploy.rb itself, but now I have another issue, not related, for puma.